# How to read from textfile and pass values to another class Java?

Tags: java

I'm making a Java program that needs to read info from a text file and then store it in an array and pass it to another class when called. My issue is that I can't seem to call it due to the IOException needed in the file reader class.

This is the main class that is supposed to call the fileReader.

```
public class window {
public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] people = readFromText.read("people.txt");
    }
}
```

File Reader Class

```
public class readFromText{
    public static String[] read(String textFile) throws IOException {
      BufferedReader inputFile = new BufferedReader(new 
      FileReader(textFile));
      String[] array = new String[10];
      String line = inputFile.readLine().toString();
      int cnt = 0;
      while (line!=null){
        array[cnt] = line;
        line = inputFile.readLine().toString();
        cnt++;
      }
      inputFile.close();
      return array;
   }
}
```

Is it possible to do this, this way?

Comment: Just add "throws Exception" to your main method: `public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception { //...`

Comment: No, never catch and ignore an exception like that.

Comment: I put the max as 10 because in my original code there was a bit that found the number of valid lines in the text file and I felt it would have been too long to include here when that isn't what is causing the issue

Comment: @JohnG sorry forgot to tag

Comment: I would always add an if statement checking if the file exists before reading/writing to files.

Comment: You do not say what the current error you are getting since you updated your code. I am betting you are getting a `NullPointerException` coming from the statement `line = inputFile.readLine().toString();`. The `toString()` method is the culprit throwing this error because the `inputFile.readLine()` portion is returning `null`. You should trace this… If we have just read the last line in the file at the statement `line = inputFile.readLine().toString();`

Comment: Now `line` contains the last string to put in the array. `cnt` is currently 8. Move to the next line where `cnt` is incremented to 9. Move back up to the `while` statement and `line` is not null so continue. Place the string from `line` into the `array` at index `cnt` (9). Move to the next line, where we actually started, and read the next line into `line`. Since we have already read the last line, `line` is going to be null and when you try to call the `toString()` method with a null value… well… you know what is going to happen.

Comment: I cannot stress enough that reading a file into a FIXED size collection is a BAD idea! You may want to look at an `ArrayList` of `Strings`.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly your code is not correct. You can not return the `String[] array` for the function need `String[][]`.
Secondly for problem about exception you just need to catch it in your main class.

```
try {
    String[] people = readFromText.read("people.txt");
} catch (IOException e) {           
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: The array issue was due to me trying to simplify the code I put on here... I actually want to return a 2d array. And if I catch the IOException it goes into a loop and doesn't do what's after the call